# $a_n>0$, $\sum a_n^2<+\infty$, and $\sum a_{n_k}=+\infty$ whenever $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}=1\;?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that:

- $a_n>0$ for all positive integer $n$,
- $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2<+\infty$, and
- $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{n_k}=+\infty$ for any subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}=1\;?$

Note that common simple sequences like $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ fail to meet the third condition. For example $n_k=\lfloor k(\log k)^2\rfloor+1$ then $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}=1$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}\leq 1+\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(\log k)^2}<+\infty$.

Comment: Have you tried $1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 ....$?

Comment: @DS $a_n=1/n$ fails to meet the third condition. See the comment below  the first answer

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you proved thet $a_n=1/n$ is not a counterexample.

Comment: Y.Lin, please add more context to you question, write all you tried in order to solve your problem. If you do it, I will help you.

Comment: Easier yet: Take $n_k=k^d$ for any $d\ge 2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, also $d>1$.

Comment: @Angelo We ‘are’ talking about subsequences of positive integers!

Comment: @TedShifrin, I mean $n_k=\left\lfloor k^d\right\rfloor+1$ where $d>1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

> **Proposition.** Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be such that $a_n>0$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2<+\infty$, then there exists a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}=1$ such that
> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_k}<+\infty.$$

*Proof.* For any $k\geq 1$, take $n_k\in[k^4+1, (k+1)^4]$ such that
$$a_{n_k}=\min_{k^4+1\leq n\leq(k+1)^4}a_n,$$
then we have $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}=1$ and
$$((k+1)^4-k^4)a_{n_k}^2\leq \sum_{n=k^4+1}^{(k+1)^4}a_n^2\leq M$$
for some $M\in(0,+\infty)$, hence
$$a_{n_k}\leq\frac C{k^{3/2}}$$
for some $C>0$ and for all $k\gg1$, therefore $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_k}<+\infty.$

Comment: Congratulations, I like your answer very much !

Comment: @Angelo Thanks for your nice comment!

Comment: Feng, if you agree, I would like to generalize your proposition.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Feng is very good and I would like to generalize the Proposition he wrote.

**Proposition generalized:**

Let $\;f:(0,+\infty)\to(0,+\infty)\;$ be a monotonically increasing function and $\,b>0\,$ such that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{f(x)}{x^b}=l\in\Bbb R^+\cup\{+\infty\}\,.$
Let $\,\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\,$ be a sequence such that $\,a_n>0\,$ for all $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ and $\,\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f\left(a_n\right)\,$ converges, then there exists a subsequence $\,\{a_{n_k}\}_{k\in\Bbb N}\,$ with $\,\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}=1\,$ such that $\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_k}$ converges.

**Proof:**

For any $\,k\in\Bbb N\,,\,$ we take $\,n_k\in\left[k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}+1,
\left(k+1\right)^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}\right]\,$ such that $\;a_{n_k}=\min\limits_{k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}+1\leqslant n\leqslant\left(k+1\right)^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}}a_n\;\;,\;\;$
then we have that

$\dfrac{(k+1)^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}+1}{(k+1)^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}}\leqslant\dfrac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}\leqslant\dfrac{(k+2)^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}}{k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}+1}\;\;,$

consequently , $\;\;\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}=1\,.$

Moreover, it results that

$\left(\lfloor b\rfloor+2\right)k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+1}f\left(a_{n_k}\right)\leqslant\left[(k+1)^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}-k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}\right]f\left(a_{n_k}\right)\leqslant\\[3pt]\underset{\overbrace{\;\text{ because }f\text{ is increasing }\;}}{\leqslant}\sum\limits_{n=k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}+1}^{(k+1)^{\lfloor b\rfloor+2}}\!\!\!\!f\left(a_n\right)\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f\left(a_n\right)=M\;\,,$

where $\,M\in(0,+\infty)\;,\;$ hence

$f\left(a_{n_k}\right)\leqslant\dfrac M{\left(\lfloor b\rfloor+2\right)k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+1}}\;\;\;$ for any $\,k\in\Bbb N\,.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{f(x)}{x^b}=l\in\Bbb R^+\!\cup\{+\infty\}\,,\,$ there exist $\,C>0\,$ and $\,\delta>0\,$ such that $\;f(x)>Cx^b\;\;$ for any $\,x\in(0,\delta)\,.\quad\color{blue}{(2)}$

Since $\,\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left[\dfrac M{C\left(\lfloor b\rfloor+2\right)k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+1}}\right]^{\frac 1b}\!\!\!=0<\delta\,,\,$ there exists $\,k_0\in\Bbb N\;$ such that $\;x_k^*=\left[\dfrac M{C\left(\lfloor b\rfloor+2\right)k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+1}}\right]^{\frac 1b}\!\!\!\in(0,\delta)\;\;$ for any $\,k\geqslant k_0\,.$

From $\,(1)\,$ and from $\,(2)\,$ applied for $\,x=x_k^*\,,\,$ it follows that

$f\left(a_{n_k}\!\right)\leqslant\dfrac M{\left(\lfloor b\rfloor\!+\!2\right)k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+1}}=Cx_k^{*b}\!<f(x_k^*)\;\;$ for any $\,k\geqslant k_0\,$

and, since $\,f\,$ is monotonically increasing, we get that

$a_{n_k}<x_k^*=\left[\dfrac M{C\left(\lfloor b\rfloor+2\right)k^{\lfloor b\rfloor+1}}\right]^{\frac 1b}\;\;$ for any $\,k\geqslant k_0\,.$

By letting $\;N=\left[\dfrac M{C\left(\lfloor b\rfloor+2\right)}\right]^{\frac 1b}\!\!>0\;,\;\;d=\dfrac{\lfloor b\rfloor\!+\!1}b>1\;,\\$
it follows that $\;a_{n_k}<\dfrac N{k^d}\;\;$ for any $\,k\geqslant k_0\;$ and consequently the series $\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_{n_k}\,$ converges.

---

If the function $\,f\,$ is $\,f(x)=x^2\,$ for any $\,x\in(0,+\infty)\,,\,$ we get the Proposition of Feng.

Comment: +1 Nice generalization!

Comment: @Feng, it was possible thanks to your good answer.